# Finding length of range in C++

Tags: c++, range, c++14, std, counting

I have defied a range and I need to find the number of elements in it. My current code is

```
size_t c = 0;
for(auto elem : range){
     c++;
}
return c;
```

However, the compiler is whining about the unused variable `elem` and I can't get rid of it. I though of using something like

```
std::count_if(range.begin(), range.end(), [](type elem){return ture;});
```

But I feel it is an overkill and it does not seem right.

I am wondering if there is a nicer systematic way of achieving this without defining an extra variable?

Comment: Isn't there `range.size()`? Which type is `range`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If (for some reason) your range doesn't have a `size()` member function, you can use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). This should always work since a range is required to have a begin and end iterator.

```
std::distance(cbegin(range), cend(range));
```

Comment: std::distance did not work. Compiler message: 
template argument/substitution failed.
Error: no type named 'diffrerence_type' in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<dynamic_graph::my_range::iterator>’

Comment: @narekBojikian Your iterator needs to define its own `difference_type`. If you can't change the code for the range then just use a simple non-range for loop `for (auto i=range.begin();i!=range.end();i++)c++;`

Comment: I can change the code I implemented it myself. But how should 'difference_type' look like?

Comment: @narekBojikian you can read about the types [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). For `difference_type` you need a signed integer. You can just declare it as  `using distance_type = long long;` inside your iterator class.

Comment: I still have another problem. Begin and end iterators are of different types. end is just an 'empty-type' that triggers an internal test in begin to test internally whether there are more elements to iterate over. std:: distance expects both to be of the same type. Do you think I can overcome this without having to modify my iterator? (It would work with a wrapper that is either an iterator or 'empty-type' but I am looking for something more elegant

Comment: @narekBojikian that is some strange range you have there. What categories do they have (input, forward, random access, ...) and how do you determine if an iterator is the end iterator?

Comment: My iterator is a wrapper over vector::iterator that skips some elements. Something like boost::adaptors::filtered. The reason I am keeping begin and end in begin is that I also have to keep a reference to the vector and some other data for filtering and I thought I can spare some space in avoiding making copy of everything. I could have made end-iterator keep only end reference and ignore all other iterators but the class would not be nice (I wouldn't have explicit constructor and I will have to turn the reference to the vector into a pointer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) like

```
std::distance(range.begin(), range.end());
```

> Returns the number of hops from `first` to `last`.

And note the complexity:

> **Complexity**
>
> Linear.
>
> However, if `InputIt` additionally meets the requirements of
>   [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator),
>   complexity is constant.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ all the [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) implement `size` method of a constant complexity so if by `range` you consider a container then there is **no need** for reinventing the wheel.

However, you can also use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) if you want to determine the number of elements from a certain range like:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v{ 3, 1, 4 };
std::cout << std::distance(v.begin(), v.end() << std::endl; // 3
```

If you take a look at the possible implementation of `std::distance`, it is something like

```cpp
while (first != last) {
    ++first;
    ++n;
}
```

where `first` and the `last` are start and end point of you range, and `n` is a simple counter.

Comment: It is worth noting that a range-based for loop can be used for other types than the ones who fulfil the container trait. The only requirement is that the type defines `begin()` and `end()`, therefor the posted answers using `std::distance` are more generic.