# Get the size of a join_view with range-v3

Tags: c++, range-v3

I am trying to get the size of a joint_view created from two std::vector. That should give me the sum of the sizes.

```
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> s0;
    s0.push_back(0);
    s0.push_back(2);
…
    auto sc{s | 
            ranges::views::transform([](const auto &segment) {return segment;}) | ranges::views::join};

    auto nVertices{std::size(sc)};
    for (const auto &v : sc) {
        std::cout << v << "\n";
```

https://godbolt.org/z/o3Yzafrfj

However, I am getting a compile error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:26:29: error: no matching function for call to 'size(ranges::join_view<ranges::transform_view<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >, main()::<lambda(const auto:7&)> > >&)'
   26 |     auto nVertices{std::size(sc)};
...
```

Why can't I ask the size of the range in this case?

Comment: I think this is explained by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364044/finding-length-of-range-in-c. Though you have to use `ranges::distances` instead, see https://godbolt.org/z/5hz5ob66K. I am unsure this comment is worth becoming an answer, since I don't really know how the linked question is generic enough to consider this question a duplicate.
Someone please ping me with some thoughts about the situation so I can remove this comment or turn it into an answer `:)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding length of range in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364044/finding-length-of-range-in-c)

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk it doesn't answer the question, unfortunately. std::distance doesnt work (I already tested it before posting here). However, using ranges::distance works, as Erel suggested

Comment: @Erel You should make this an answer then. As there is a difference in the functions used.

Comment: Note that here I am using range-v3. Could be that for std::ranges, std::distance makes sense, I havent tested that case

Comment: @jjcasmar That is the case.  ranges-V3 was the precursor to std::ranges.  `std::size` only works if the thing has a size member and a lazy range like yours can't since it hasn't done the evaluation yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some `ranges` don't provide a `size()` function, so calling `std::size()` (which really just calls the member function) is ineffective.

With ranges of the Standard Library, you can call `std::distance(std::cbegin(range), std::cend(range))` (resp. with `begin` and `end` when the ranges does not provide `const` iterators).

With [ranges-v3](/questions/tagged/ranges-v3), the method is the same, but with `ranges::distance`.

Note that since your range doesn't provide `cbegin` (resp. `cend`), you must use the non-`const` counterpart as:

```cpp
auto nVertices = ranges::distance(sc.begin(), sc.end());
```

See it live here: https://godbolt.org/z/j4Eb4svrd